# SocketIO web socket must be placed on Angular Service class

Tags: angular, sockets, socket.io

I'm using Angular and SocketIO to build a card game simulator. I have a game service that uses the web socket to send and receive messages from the server.

If I a put the web socket as a private property of the service everything works fine.

```
@Injectable()
export class GameService {
private socket = io(environment.ws_url

playCards(card): {
  this.socket.emit('play_card', card)
}
...
```

The problem with this approach is that I'd like to use this GameService in multiple places. If I use the service in multiple places then I create unwanted socket connections.

I've tried setting the socket to a constant like this

```
const socket = io(environment.ws_url)

@Injectable()
export class GameService {
  playCards(card): {
    socket.emit('play_card', card)
 }
}
...
```

This works in ensuring only 1 connection per client is created. However, the responses from the server take >5 seconds to be received by the front-end, and the UI only updates from the client that preformed the action. Any idea why?

How can I ensure only one web socket per client, and still re-use the socket/service in other components?

I'd really like to be able to use this service in multiple places as it would make things a lot easier.

As a workaround, I can always just emit events from my components to a root component that will be the only importer of the GameService. That approach is very cumbersome, and I'd like to avoid having to do that

EDIT:
I guess my issues comes from that the socket communication is sometimes done outside the angular zone. Wrapping the socket responses with `this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(data))` solved my issue and allows me to use the service in multiple places without creating new connections.

Comment: Why not use the DI system to provide a value where needed? Various options are covered here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers

Comment: I am doing that. The problem is that in the first case (have socket as a property on the service) results in a new socket connection being created every time the service is injected. In the second case, the problem is that communication time for the socket is too long, and the UI does not update when it receives a response

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to create one on connection per client by using this method

```
const socket = io(environment.ws_url);
@Injectable()
export class GameService {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}
  private socket = socket;
  private createObservalble<T>(message: string): Observable<T> {
    const observable = new Observable<T>((observer) => {
      this.socket.on(message, (data: T) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(data));
        // In case of error, disconnect
        return () => this.socket.disconnect();
      });
    });
    return observable;
  }
```

Using this method results in the socket communication occurring outside the angular zone and I needed to add the line `this.ngZone.run(() => observer.next(data));` to force the UI to update